# codeigniter update function gets 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created an update function but i keep getting a 404 error, i cant figure out what seems to be the problem. help would be appriciated thank you .

controller news.php

```
 public function update($id)

    {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
   'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
   'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
   'slug' => $this->input->post('slug'),
    );
   if($this->news_model->exists($id)) {
   $this->news_model->update($id, $data);
   } else {
   $this->news_model->insert($data);
  }

  }
```

news_model.php

```
public function update_news($id, $data)
{
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('news', $data); 
}
```

route

```
$route['news/update/(:num)'] = 'news/update/$1';
```

views

update.php

```
 <h2>Update an item</h2>

 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

 <?php echo form_open('/news/update'.$news_item['id']) ?>


<label for="title">Title</label> 
<input type="input" name="title" /><br />

 <label for="slug">Slug</label> 
 <input type="input" name="slug" /><br />

<label for="text">Text</label>
 <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update an item" /> 

 </form>
```

index.php

```
 <p><a href="news/update/<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>">update article</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get 404 when submitting the form?

Try to change the form opening to:

```
<?php echo form_open($news_item['id']) ?>
```

or if you have the uri helper activiated:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'news/update/'.$news_item['id']) ?>
```

Comment: i did what you said and i still get a error, when trying to open the update page through the link .......codeigniter/index.php/news/update i get a 404 error so the update page does not appear nor does the form

Comment: another thing when i click update      /codeigniter/index.php/news/news/update/47    'news' appears twice

Comment: ok. does the page show up if you remove your line in routes.php ?  use absolute paths (base_url()) instead then you do not wnd up with news showing twice in the url

Comment: i cannot submit the update because it doesnt load up it says 404 error when i click update article in the news page.

Answer (score 0):

try to load URL helper and from the config file in the config folder set the `base_url` to yourpath or yourpath/index.php if you use index.php for ex. `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php`, and update the view to be
`<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'news/update/'.$news_item['id']) ?>`

Comment: when i do this i have problems with my create button to create articles

Comment: whats is the problem? you can use base_url also ex: `base_url().controller/action`

Comment: with the code that i have above, when i type in the url to the views update page the page does not appear, when i put the routes in and type in the url for the update page it still does not appear so when i am clicking the update link from the articles page i am getting a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a forward slash in your form open.  You have

```
<?php echo form_open('/news/update'.$news_item['id']) ?>
```

but it should be

```
<?php echo form_open('/news/update/'.$news_item['id']) ?>
```

Also I agree with @Mohamed Nagy you should load the url helper and use the base_url()

A couple of other things I noticed is that in your model your update function is called update_news() but in your controller you are calling update().  This is probably causing an error

Also why are you using `$this->uri->segment(3);` to get the id when you are passing it to the function anyway?

Comment: i have taken out segment 3 and i have put in the missing the forward slash so it reads   <?php echo form_open('/news/update/'.$news_item['id']) ?>   but still the page doesnt load and i get a 404 error

Comment: In the model you are calling $this->news_model->update($id, $data); but you need to change this to $this->news_model->update_news($id, $data); have you done this?